# Assign group number based on row criteria [Python]

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, rank

I have a dataframe with column 'type' and want to create a column 'group' that assigns a group number when type = 'a'.

Starting data (ignore index, copied from jupyter notebook):

```py
df = pd.DataFrame ({'type':
['a','b','a','b','b','a','b','b','b','b','b','b']})
```

```py
Index   type
0   a
1   b
2   a
3   b
4   b
5   a
6   b
7   b
8   b
9   b
10  b
11  b
```

output should be:

```py
type    grouping
a   1
b   1
a   2
b   2
b   2
a   3
b   3
b   3
b   3
b   3
b   3
b   3
```

Comment: the `grouping` is the occurrence number?

Comment: see my answer and let me know if it helps

Comment: Thank you @serafeim ! This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear how you define the grouping but your desired output can be achieved by using `cumsum` and `eq`:

```
df['grouping']=df['type'].eq('a').cumsum()
```

Output:

```
   type  grouping
0     a         1
1     b         1
2     a         2
3     b         2
4     b         2
5     a         3
6     b         3
7     b         3
8     b         3
9     b         3
10    b         3
11    b         3
```